Showing information from one ACF Field Group with another
I have two ACF Field Groups, that two different post types will use.
Post type one will use field-group-one
Post type two will use field-group-two
There is a lot of information already stored in field-group-one that will need to be added to field-group-two without them using the same Post types (so I can have two different Post Types and single templates).
What I've done so far is in field-group-two I've added a Post Object field called "linked-post" so that a user can select a post from Post type one that will have the data we need.
When I add the following code to the site the ID of the post is displayed correctly:
<?php $linked-post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'linked-post', $single = true); ?><?php the_field('linked-post'); ?>

What I want to do is get the ID outputted so that I can then add it to the following:
<?php $data_01 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_01', $single = true); ?>

Where get_post-meta($post->ID is I'd like to replace $post->ID with the_field('linked-post') so that it grabs the data from the other post.
I've tried all sorts of ways but I'm a bit rusty with my PHP and hoping it's something a set of fresh eyes can see. Also, if there is a simpler way of linking two ACF field groups together that already uses the data that's been set that would be great.
Thank you.
I tried all sorts of ways to pass the linked-post ID to the $post->ID but nothing seems to work.

the_field() - outputs the value of the field. To simply get it, use get_field().
Something like this:
$linked_post = get_field( 'linked-post' );
$data_01 = get_field( 'data_01', $linked_post );

